# Why I can't dowload a file by click with Playwright

Tags: button, download, click, playwright

I create a csv-File on a server. Then I want do download by click to a button.
Manually it works fine. But if I click to download button by Playwright.
How is the right way to do that.

Thnak you for Help

Comment: See https://playwright.dev/docs/downloads

Answer (score 0):

You have this in playwright doc. Do the homework please.

```
const [ download ] = await Promise.all([
  // Start waiting for the download
  page.waitForEvent('download'),
  // Perform the action that initiates download
  page.click('button#delayed-download')
]);
// Wait for the download process to complete
const path = await download.path();
```

See playwright.dev/docs/downloads, as already mentioned